# Two iframe's. A menu with links. The other, where the websites appear. I need the websites to always appear in the iframe

Tags: html, css

Demo: http://mydemos.site90.net/

Basically it's a web protal of my different sites. When a user clicks one of the links the site to show up downsized to fit in the iframe on the left. and as the user go through the site the site stays in the iframe instead of opening in anther window. And googles translater to translate what ever is in the iframe. Googles translater is showing it's search bar and menu up top for some reason after translation and some of the sites are not being downsized. I'm new to coding so my code might be measy. any help is much needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet --><HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Demo</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<STYLE type=text/css>BODY {
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #000000
}
</STYLE>

<STYLE type=text/css>A:link {
COLOR: #bdbdbd
}
A:visited {
COLOR: #bdbdbd
}
A:hover {
COLOR: #ffffff; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
A:active {
COLOR: #bdbdbd; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
</STYLE>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> 
<style type="text/css">    
img { behavior: url("pngfix.htc"); } 
</style> 
<![endif]-->
<STYLE type=text/css media=screen>#YouTube2 {
VISIBILITY: hidden
}
</STYLE>

<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.19394"></HEAD>
<BODY>

<IFRAME 
style="Z-INDEX: 10; POSITION: fixed; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;         BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 79%; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;     BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; HEIGHT: 100%; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; TOP: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px;      LEFT: 0px" 
id=iframe1 border=0 src="http://www.crimemapping.com/map.aspx" frameBorder=0     name=iframe1 
cellspacing="0"></IFRAME></IFRAME>


<DIV 
style="Z-INDEX: 10; POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN:     0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 134px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; HEIGHT: 20px; TOP: 9px; PADDING-      TOP: 0px; LEFT: 80%" 
id=bv_Text2><A style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" 
href="http://craigslist.com/"><SPAN 
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-SIZE: 18px"><STRONG><I>DEMO<SPAN 
style="COLOR: red">D</SPAN>DEMO</I></STRONG></SPAN></A></DIV></A></B></SPAN>
<DIV> </DIV>


<DIV 
style="Z-INDEX: 10; POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN:     0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 49px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; HEIGHT: 16px; TOP: 50px; PADDING-    TOP: 0px; LEFT: 80%" 
id=bv_Text15><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-SIZE: 20px" 
face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><B><A style="TEXT-DECORATION: none"> <a><a     href="http://free-website-translation.com/" id="ftwtranslation_button" hreflang="en"     title="" style="border:0;"><img src="http://free-website-    translation.com/img/fwt_button_en.gif" id="ftwtranslation_image" alt="Free Website     Translator" style="border:0;"/></a> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://free-website-    translation.com/scripts/fwt.js" /></script></A></B></SPAN></DIV>


<DIV 
style="Z-INDEX: 10; POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; MARGIN:     0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 49px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; HEIGHT: 16px; TOP: 100px; PADDING-  TOP: 0px; LEFT: 80%" 
id=bv_Text15><SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-SIZE: 20px" 
face="Arial" color="#FFFFFF"><B><A style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" 
href="http://www.youtube.com" <a>Demo1</A></B></SPAN></DIV>






</body>

</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `ID`s for your `iframe` elements first, then you can set links in the other `iframe` to point to the first `iframe` by providing `target` ID in your anchor `A` tags `target="iframe1"`. Suppose you have a simple two `iframe`s web layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>link from one iframe to another iframe</title>
  <head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframe2" src="some_page_with_links.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the `some_page_with_links.html` document from `iframe2` has this structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>this is iframe2 that contains links to iframe1</title>
  <head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="iframe1">open Google in iframe1</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The link in the `iframe2` will then tell the browser to open it in your `iframe1`, as set by the `target` property of your anchor `A` tag.

*Do note however, that this won't work for external domains in case you have set `X-Frame-Options` response header to `SAMEORIGIN` in your web server. Other limitations might apply, depending on your configuration and if you plan on linking to external domains.*

I've also noted you have some HTML tag closing errors in your example that you linked to. For example:

```
<A style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="www.ebay.com" <a>Demo2</A>
```

should really be:

```
<A style="TEXT-DECORATION: none" href="www.ebay.com" target="ID_of_iframe1">Demo2</A>
```

Cheers!